# How to connect Power BI Desktop to remote MySql server that requires authentication

Tags: mysql, authentication

I have a MySql database running on a remote server which requires ssh authentication that I need to connect to with Microsoft Power BI.  I can easily connect to MySQL on my localhost machine, but cannot find a way to manage both the server ssh authentication and the database user log on information.

The server requires authentication on port 22 with a username and password and the MySQL database requires a different username and password.

Can anyone offer assistance?

Answer (score 2):

It seems possible to connect remotely, though I'm not sure you can do it through an 'SSH tunnel' on port 22.

There's a discussion here about connecting remotely which sounds to me like a connection to the usual port 3306, though I'm not certain:

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Integrations-with-Files-and/Cannot-Connect-to-MySQL-on-Linux-VM/td-p/94914

Some common pitfalls:

1) Make sure you download the correct version of MySQL/Net connector.  As of now, version 6.6.5 seems to be working.  I wasted a lot of time trying to figure out what was wrong with earlier versions.

2) Server & database settings:  closed ports / user permissions / bind-address

Before connecting PowerBI, try to connect another utility like MySQL Workbench.  This will force you to troubleshoot the above settings.

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently possible with PowerBI. The feature is currently under review, and you can help get it prioritized by upvoting here:

https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/7020353-mysql-over-ssh-connection

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is supported (yet) but it looks like a lot of people want a solution including me. See this [Power BI Ideas Request](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/7020353-mysql-over-ssh-connection)

Answer (score 0):

1) create gateway to connect server then

2) then it will ask connection string their you can give server port and  database username and password

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be an error in the remote servers firewall configuration.

After further research I have confirmed that Power BI would not support dual authentication steps like logging onto a remote server with ssh and then connecting to the database.  Thanks Robin for your suggestion.  That was a key point.

Answer (score 0):

Please remember that for remote connections you need to authorise the mysql users to connect from specific hosts (adding the IP) or `%` to allow to get connected from any host remotely

the SQL is something similar to:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

[How to allow remote connection to mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779104/how-to-allow-remote-connection-to-mysql)